# Preprocessor not using defined hashed value but definition string for macro

Tags: c, hash, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to make an easy way of defining my IO. I'm trying to do this with a macro but I can't solve this problem.

I did this:

```
// Buzzer PORT and PIN mapping
#define BUZZER_PORT     B       // PORT
#define BUZZER_PIN      2       // PCR pin
#define BUZZER_ALT      1       // Pin alternativne function

#define INIT_BUZZER(PORTX, PIN, ALT) { PORT##PORTX##_PCR(PIN) = PORT_PCR_MUX((ALT)) |     PORT_PCR_DSE_MASK;            GPIO##PORTX##_PDDR |= PIN<<1; }
```

Function call working:

```
INIT_BUZZER(B, BUZZER_PIN, BUZZER_ALT);
```

Function call wanted:

```
INIT_BUZZER(BUZZER_PORT, BUZZER_PIN, BUZZER_ALT);
```

If I call it with port argument BUZZER_PORT I get an error because compiler doesn't take my arguments value but string itself.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

use brackets as most as possible.

try below：
INIT_BUZZER((BUZZER_PORT), BUZZER_PIN, BUZZER_ALT);

Answer (score 0):

You need an indirection:

```
#define INIT_BUZZER_(PORTX, PIN, ALT)                                   \
    do {                                                                \
        PORT##PORTX##_PCR(PIN) = PORT_PCR_MUX(ALT) | PORT_PCR_DSE_MASK; \
        GPIO##PORTX##_PDDR |= (PIN)<<1;                                 \
    } while (0)

#define INIT_BUZZER(PORTX, PIN, ALT)                                    \
        INIT_BUZZER_(PORTX, PIN, ALT)
```

Also note the `do {...} while(0)` and no semi-colon, which is the normal way to enclose several lines in a macro

Comment: Thank you. In that situation it works.

What if I want to define a macro of toggle pin without argument something like this: